# Python : How to create multiple CSV from the large pandas dataframe without duplicating the records in CSV's created

Tags: python, pandas

I have 1 million records in the dataframe and would like to save into CSVs with 100k each. I did it like below method but it saved all the 1 million records in one CSV and Not in multiple CSV's.

```
out_file = open(outdir + out_file_m.csv,'w')
pd.df_.to_csv(out_file, chunksize = 100000, index = None, header = True)
```

Comment: thats not what 'chunksize' is for. you'll need to split it up into the size you want and write each one to file. Idk of a built in way to do what you want

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is. Have you not read the documentation for `read_csv` concerning the `chunksize` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a For loop and just grab 100000 lines in each iteration and save that, do it 10 times, you can use a counter to adjust the file naming appropriately. :)

(Updated for the type conversion issue on the c variable being used in the name)

```
size = 100000
for x in range(0, len(df)//size):     
    f = x*size
    t = min((x+1)*size, len(df))
    file_name = f"CSV_{x+1}.csv"
    df[f:t].to_csv(file_name, index=False)
```

This should be pretty close. :)

Comment: Please share few lines of code to understand thoroughly. That really helps.

Comment: thanks for reply. There is an error ...... file_name = 'CSV_' + c + '.csv'

TypeError: must be str, not int

Comment: Thanks @FBruzzesi, I thought about that update when I got home last night.  There's a few more ways to optimize it and clean it up.  Ideally we'd want to run this against the size of the dataframe so we can get the partial file at the end if it's not exactly 1,000,000 rows.  Maybe MOD can be used. :)

Comment: Thanks @FBruzzesi, The type conversion I resolved by adding str(c) and it worked.

Comment: Thanks!  Added your suggestions, pretty much in line with what was in my head. #highfive

Comment: You can use `divmod` to get integer division and its remainder, yet in my opinion the code would get uglier :)